# Delete Button not working with json server using angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs

I am doing angular crud operation using JSON server, post and get are working properly but delete is not working DELETE /posts1 404. My code is as follows -

```
deleteEmployee(id : number){
    return this.http.delete<any>("http://localhost:3000/posts"+id)
    .pipe(map((res:any)=>{
      return res;
    })
```

DELETE http://localhost:3000/posts1 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fix url

```
 return this.http.delete<any>("http://localhost:3000/posts/"+id)
```

or maybe

```
 return this.http.delete<any>("http://localhost:3000/posts?id="+id)
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance but I tried changing the URL still negative. Below is the code for posting data, it is working as intended:
  postEmployee(data : any){
    return this.http.post<any>("http://localhost:3000/posts",data)
    .pipe(map((res:any)=>{
      return res;
    }))
  }
maybe the variable "id"  is the one causing the URL to change after compilation 
POST /posts 500 44.465 ms - -
GET /posts 304 23.084 ms - -
POST /posts 201 26.434 ms - 161
GET /posts 200 21.063 ms - 539
DELETE /posts1 404 15.017 ms - 2

Comment: I would like to see 3000/posts API. Can you post the code pls?

Comment: deleteEmployee(row : any){
    this.api.deleteEmployee(row.id)
    .subscribe(res=>{
      alert("Employee Deleted!")
      this.getAllEmployee();
    },

Comment: Done!! Thank you man, the issue was with the URL   
deleteEmployee(id : number){
 return this.http.delete<any>(`${'http://localhost:3000/posts'}/${id}`)
    .pipe(map((res:any)=>{
      return res;
    }))
  }